# char-Tables, Segmentation Error

Tags: c

I'm currently learning the C programming language, and I'm having some issues with it.

I'm getting `Segmentation Error` quite a lot when dealing with string (A.K.A char tables)

Here a simple algorithm just to delete the '**e**' letter in the input string.

**Example:**

"hackers does exist" ->>> "hacks dos xist"

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
   char T[200];
   int j,i,l,times=0;
   printf("Entre THE TXT\n");
   gets(T);
   while (T[i] != '\0')
  {
    l++;
    i++;
  }
  for (i=0;i<l;i++)
  {
     if ( T[i] == 'e')
     {
        times++;
     }
  }

  l=l-times;
  i=0;
  j=0;
  while (i<l)
  {
    if ( T[j] != 'e')
    {
       T[i]=T[j];
       i++;
       j++;
    }
    else j++;
  }
  for (i=0;i<l;i++)
  {
        printf("%c",T[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Can you please tell me what I did wrong?

PS: I have noticed that each time I do incrementation as `j++` in this code I will get the `Segmentation Error`... I really don't understand why.

Comment: Never use `gets`, ever. It was mis-designed and cannot be used safely. Use `fgets(T, sizeof(T), stdin)` instead. Also, compile with `-Wall` to get a reasonable level of compiler warnings.

Comment: Don't call it table but Array. Please use descriptive variable names, for example `l` could be `len`, `length` or even `text_length`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [kiran Biradar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4431643/kiran-biradar) already answered you only missed to initialize your integers.
You have several options here. I'll write them from most common to most discouraged.

Most used form, verbose but easier to maintain later.

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int l = 0;
int times = 0;
```

Short form 1:

```
int i = 0, j = 0, l = 0, times 0;
```

Short form 2:

```
int i, j, l, times;
i = j = l = times = 0;
```

---

I'd suggest you also to use the features of at least the `C99` Standard and reduce the scope of your variables completely. (Yes I know it's possible with `{}`-Blocks but I kinda like for-loops, if you iterate completely over something.
Hence my suggestion for your code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> // str(n)len

int main(void) // argv/argc is never used
{
    char text[200];

    printf("Entre THE TXT\n");
    if (fgets(text, sizeof(text), stdin) == NULL) // fgets as gets is deprecated
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    size_t len = strlen(text); // returns number of Characters excluding '\0'
    if (len > 0 && text[len-1] == '\n') { // strip newline if present from fgets
        text[len-1] = '\0';
    }

    unsigned int times = 0;
    for (size_t i=0; i<len; i++) {
        if (text[i] == 'e') {
            times++;
        }
    }

    // I'd prefer to use a `newlen` variable
    len -= (size_t) times;
    for (size_t j=0, i=0; i < len; j++) {
        if (text[j] != 'e') {
            text[i] = text[j];
            i++;
        }
    }
    text[len] = '\0'; // just for safety reasons terminate string properly

    puts(text);       // Use puts instead of calling printf several times.

    return 0;
}
```

Further improvements:
Actually the `times` could be eliminated, as it's not really used to delete `e`s.
So just remove the times block and all lines with it.

Answer (score 3):

Initialize `i, j, l` variables. Since uninitialized local variables are indeterminate. Reading them prior to assigning a value results in undefined behavior.

You are accessing the `i` and `l` variable without initialization.

```
  while (T[i] != '\0')
  {
    l++;
    i++;
  }
```

Initialize as below.

```
  int j = 0, i = 0, l = 0, times = 0;
```

Comment: oh It Worked , it was just a initialization issue .
I thought 

    int j,i,l,times=0; is the same as   int j = 0, i = 0, l = 0, times = 0;

Comment: No, you have initialize each variable separately.